# php OOP find out if method argument is a method in child class

Tags: php, class, methods

The code sample is an simple example for what i'm working on.
I have 2 classes in php.

```
class Wrap {

    public function wrapA($arg){
        return 'A'.$arg.'A';
    }

    public function wrapB($arg){
        return 'B'.$arg.'B';
    }

}

class Child extends Wrap {

    public $OUT;

    public function wrapA($arg){
        $this->OUT .= parent::wrapA($arg);
    }

    public function wrapB($arg){
        $this->OUT .= parent::wrapB($arg);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo $this->OUT;
    }

}

$X = new Child();

$X->wrapA(
    $X->wrapB('CC')
);
```

The Output here is "**BCCBAA**". But what I try to achieve is "**ABCCBA**".
The "Wrap" class must be in this form.

… and if I have the following method-calls:

> $X->wrapB(    $X->wrapA('1') );
>
> $X->wrapA(    $X->wrapB('aa')     .$X->wrapA('bbb')   .$X->wrapB(
>         $X->wrapA('cccc')   ) );

… i want to have the following output: **BA1ABABaaBAbbbABAcccABA**

Is there an other way?

I also want the Wrap-Class to work alone (without Child) … this is why the methods have return-value.

But in Child-Class I want to write the return-values in a variable.

THX in advance!

Comment: `Is it possible to check if "$arg" is a function/method or not?` No. $arg will never be a function or method in this case. It's the return value of another method call.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `$X->wrapB('CC')` doesn't return anything and gets cast to an empty string by the time `$X->wrapA()` is called, thus `A` gets wrapped around nothing.

However, because you append `BCCB` to `$X->OUT`, by the time you call `$X->wrapA()`, it appends `AA` to that, leading to `BCCBAA`.

After looking at the question again, I feel that it should be solved in another way; this is something to consider:

```
class Wrap
{
    // The wrapping itself can be declared as a static method
    protected static function wrapWithChar($arg, $ch)
    {
        return $ch . $arg . $ch;
    }
}

class Child extends Wrap
{
    protected $OUT;

    // we allow the internal state to be set upon construction
    public function __construct($s = '')
    {
        $this->OUT = $s;
    }

    // no arguments required here, this gets applied on the internal state
    public function wrapA()
    {
        $this->OUT = self::wrapWithChar($this->OUT, 'A');
        // return instance to allow chaining
        return $this;
    }

    public function wrapB()
    {
        $this->OUT = self::wrapWithChar($this->OUT, 'B');
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->OUT;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo $this->OUT;
    }

}

// initialize with 'CC'    
$X = new Child('CC');

// wrap B around it; becomes 'BCCB'
$X->wrapB();
// wrap A around that; becomes 'ABCCBA'
$X->wrapA();

// example of chaining
$Y = new Child('ZZ');
// wrap B then A around it; becomes 'ABZZBA'
$Y->wrapB()->wrapA();
```

**Old answer**

To make `Child` appear as something that `Wrap` can perform on, you could make use of the `__toString()` magic method (using `instanceof` would be more explicit, but also a bit more work):

```
class Child extends Wrap
{
    public $OUT;

    public function wrapA($arg)
    {
        $this->OUT = parent::wrapA($arg);
        return $this;
    }

    public function wrapB($arg)
    {
        $this->OUT = parent::wrapB($arg);
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->OUT;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo $this->OUT;
    }
}
```

Each `wrapX()` method now returns the instance itself, and `__toString()` gets called whenever it needs to be wrapped.

The above will generate the correct result.

Comment: what effect should `return $this->OUT . parent::wrapX($arg);` have?
Your answer doesn't help, because it does not solve the problem. It just shows in a detailed way what is happening…

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith From my perspective, the exact solution to the (known) problem is not entirely clear because I don't know why the `Child` was created. I've updated my answer, but I doubt that would solve it either.

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith Changed a few more things and it produces the correct output, but without knowing whether the behaviour is indeed correct :)

Comment: oh ya, that would be great. i've wasted the whole day now. if you really gonna do it: THX!!!.. and try also to get correct output for `$X->wrapB(
 $X->wrapA('11')
);


$X->wrapA(
 $X->wrapB('aaa')
 .$X->wrapA('bbb')
 .$X->wrapB(
  $X->wrapA('cccc')
 )
);`

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith Thought about it again, and I think it should be solved in another way; updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my favorites as an interesting puzzle to solve.

And then found that it wasn't that complicated after I woke up and looked at the problem again.
I honestly don't think you should be using subclassing at this point since technically `Child` is not logically the a child of the `Wrap` class, it essentially seems to be a guy that wants to store the output of wrap's results.

so.. Here's my modifications that works with your original interface. Hope it's good for you ;).

It makes some very magical use of magic methods.

```
<?php
class Wrap {
    public function wrapA($arg){
        return 'A'.$arg.'A';
    }

    public function wrapB($arg){
        return 'B'.$arg.'B';
    }
}

class WrapReader{
    protected $wrapper;
    protected $currentResult;

    public function __construct(Wrap $wrapper)
    {
        $this->wrapper = $wrapper;
    }

    public function __call($method,$argument)
    {
        $argument = $argument[0];
        if(!method_exists($this->wrapper,$method))
            throw new MethodNotFoundException('Method: '.$method.'() does not exist in class: '.get_class($this->wrapper));
        $this->currentResult = $this->wrapper->$method($argument);
        return $this->currentResult;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->currentResult;
    }
}
class MethodNotFoundException extends Exception{}
```

The usage:

```
$reader = new WrapReader(new Wrap());

echo $reader->wrapB( $reader->wrapA('1') ); 
echo $reader->wrapA( $reader->wrapB('aa') .$reader->wrapA('bbb') .$reader->wrapB( $reader->wrapA('cccc') ) );
echo '<br>';

Outputs BA1ABABaaBAbbbABAccccABA
```

Which is what you posted in your original question.

Comment: sorry … 1. the "Child" class is a subclass … what i'm trying to find out here is only 1 functionality the class should have … 2. what you've written is nice but it does not work for the following calls in main-method:
`$X->wrapB(
 $X->wrapA('1')
);


$X->wrapA(
 $X->wrapB('aa')
 .$X->wrapA('bbb')
 .$X->wrapB(
  $X->wrapA('cccc')
 )
);` ($X is like $reader in your code)

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith But.. it outputs exactly what you posted in your original question :x. Actually as an edit, I noticed it doesn't have the beginning part.  Oops! I cheated by doing two echos.

Comment: ya.. that's cheating. But hey.. I don't want to use **echo** in the usage.. that is why I've posted this question here. If I use echo I don't need any modifications in the Child-class (or WrapReader).. because all methods are inherited..